# How to send Drop down Data from html form to Sheets Connected with Google Forms?

Tags: html, forms, google-forms

I have been trying hard to send the dropdown data from html forms to google sheets.

This is my [Google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScT1X-3A9Tf75BVECVeJtMAnSYzCdr87K3XVKyMvZJQOdB13Q/viewform)

I have already tried this but no success.

```
<select id="Drop">
  <option value="entry.392977065">Hi</option>
</select>
```

Please suggest edit in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLScT1X-3A9Tf75BVECVeJtMAnSYzCdr87K3XVKyMvZJQOdB13Q/formResponse"target="_self" method="POST">
<section id="contatus" class="section">
  <div class="contact-form md-m-30px-b col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Entre em contato</h2>
    <form class="contactform" action="#" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="name" class="form-xl form-control" name="entry.1816959266" required="" type="text" placeholder="name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="mobile" class="form-xl form-control" name="entry.2118312539" required="" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="id" class="form-xl form-control" name="entry.1541086304" required="" type="text" placeholder="Celular" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="email" class="form-xl form-control" maxlength="15" name="entry.108846225" required="no" type="text" placeholder="Telefone fixo" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="Drop 1" class="form-xl form-control" name="entry.392977065" required="" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="Drop 2" class="form-xl form-control" name="entry.329000339" required="" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="send" style="text-align: center;">
            <button class="btn btn-theme" name="submit" type="submit"> Enviar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

faz um teste e vê se funciona dessa forma.